# How can I make an ahk project which clicks on a particular point in a specific window and also which runs in the background?

Tags: click, window, coordinates, autohotkey

I will explain what I want my code to do:
1. I will open a window
2. I will navigate to that window and press control+q
3. I will get coordinates with a Google feature and post them in inputbox
4. The code should click on that point in that window as many times I selected (I would like to run the code in background because I want to do another task at the same time)

I wrote some code but it doesn't work as expected

```
#SingleInstance force
#persistent
$^q::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
MsgBox, The active window is "%Title%".
Inputbox, c1, , Coordinate of button you want to click on(x)
Inputbox, c2, , Coordinate of button you want to click on(y)
MsgBox %c1% , %c2%
Inputbox,times, ,How many times would you like to click?
While(times>0)
{
WinGet,b,,Title                 ;I think here is the problem
ControlClick, X%c1% Y%c2%,%b%    ;or here
Sleep, 10500
times--
}
MsgBox End
return
```

Answer (score 0):

There indeed are a few problems to fix, though fixing them still wont guarantee your code will work. `ControlClick`ing is pretty going to always be a hit or miss.

So your biggest problem is here
`WinGet,b,,Title`
Don't even know what this line is supposed to be doing.
Of course you're trying to refer to the variable `Title` which you defined above, and to do that in legacy syntax you'd wrap it in `%%`. Maybe you just forgot.
But even with that fixed, I don't know why this command is used.
You're not even specifying which sub-command to use, so it's defaulting to retrieving the hwnd of matched window.
If this is indeed what you we're going for, then you'd need to fix the `ControlClick`'s WinTitle parameter to specify that you're matching a window based on its hwnd like so:
`ControlClick, X%c1% Y%c2%, ahk_id %b%`

Matching windows based on their hwnd is actually the best practice for matching windows, but your implementation here is questionable. I'm thinking it was accidental even.
Nevertheless, let me fix the code to a more sensible implementation of hwnd matching.
I'll also get rid of legacy syntax and switch over to the newer and better expression syntax.

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#Persistent

$^q::
    ;ditched the legacy WinGetTitle command, and switched over to
    ;the WinActive function, its return value is the HWND of the
    ;matched window (active window)
    ActiveWindowHWND := WinActive("A")

    ;getting the title as well, in case you really want to see it
    ;this part can be removed though
    WinGetTitle, ActiveWindowTitle, % "ahk_id " ActiveWindowHWND

    ;concatenating strings and values by just separting them with a space
    ;and double quotes to escape a quote in an expression
    ;outer most quotes always just specify that we're writing a string
    MsgBox, % "The active window's HWND is " ActiveWindowHWND " and its title is """ ActiveWindowTitle """"

    ;explicitly specifying that these long strings are actually strings
    Inputbox, c1, , % "Coordinate of button you want to click on(x)"
    Inputbox, c2, , % "Coordinate of button you want to click on(y)"
    MsgBox, % c1 " , " c2 
    Inputbox, times, , % "How many times would you like to click?"
    While (times > 0)
    {
        ;specifying the NA option
        ;it's documented to improve reliablility, read more about it
        ;from the documentation
        ControlClick, % "x" c1 " y" c2, % "ahk_id " ActiveWindowHWND, , , , NA
        Sleep, 10500
        times--
    }
    MsgBox, % "End"
return
```

If you're completely unfamiliar with the newer and better expression syntax, you can switch back over to the legacy syntax, it'll work as well.
Just be sure to add the [`NA`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Reliability) option to the control click
Though I'd recommend the newer expression syntax, of course.
Here's a good documentation page to get started:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm

Comment: Oh.. it works perfectly(Thank you so much!!), but I have a problem with the coordinates displayed by Google. The coordinates aren't calculated from the top left corner,instead the 0,0 is a little bit lower.

Comment: What can I do? Do you think that is a good idea to find the buttons which I want to click on? Or should I "play" with screen resolution and coordinates?